# How to output pygame.image.save to a variable instead of a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame2

I want to send a `pygame.surface.Surface` to another computer using `socket` library. I tried using `pygame.image.tostring` but it took 900kb, but when I used `pygame.image.save` and I used `jpg` format it only took 45kb. But the problem is `pygame.image.save` output it to a file and `pygame.image.load` only accepts file, and it slows my program because I need bytes object and reading and writing a file 32 times per second will kill the cpu. What sould I do to transform a `pygame.surface.Surface` to a `bytes` but in `jpg` format without reading and writing files 32 times per second?
(It doesn't need to be jpg format but I want it take least possible bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative option would be to use [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) to compress the string:

```py
import zlib
```

```py
image_str = pygame.image.tostring(my_image)
compressed_image_str = zlib.compress(image_str)
```

---

Or save the image to an [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) object with [`pygame.image.save()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save):

```py
import io
```

```py
temp_io = io.BytesIO()
pygame.image.save(my_surface, temp_io, "JPEG")
```

---

Another option is to use [PLI `Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#) and [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html),  which gives you more flexibility in choosing the format:

```py
from PIL import Image
import io
```

```py
pil_string_image = pygame.image.tostring(my_surface, "RGB", False)
pli_image = Image.frombytes('RGB', my_surface.get_size(), pil_string_image, 'raw')
temp_io = io.BytesIO()
pli_image.save(temp_io, format="JPEG")
```

Comment: 263kb, better but still too much, a png file takes 163kb and jpg file takes 45kb. and we are talking about internet.

Comment: @mhn2 Which solution are you using?

Comment: I'm using io to write it in a variable and then use zlib to compress the jpg file.